# How to generate swagger spec from Javadocs on JDK 14?

Tags: jersey, swagger, java-ws

Does anyone know the analog of [swagger-doclet](https://github.com/conorroche/swagger-doclet) but which works with JDK 14?
This doclet generates swagger spec by `javax.ws.rs` annotations and javadocs and it doesn't require swagger annotations

For example, I have such endpoint:

```
/**
 * Receives sync requests from the clients and puts the received event to the queue with partition key based on the user's id.
 *
 * @param thriftRequest user's event
 * @return the number of users in the saved event.
 */
@POST
@Path("/notifications")
@Timed
public TNotificationsResponse notifications(final TNotificationsRequest thriftRequest) {
 ...
}
```

I tried `swagger-core` but it generates spec ignoring javadocs :(